# What's the projection of the $x + 5y + z = 4$ plane onto the $xy$ plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus, plane-geometry, projection

The vector field:

$$F = 10xy^2 \hat{i} + (4z-2xy^2) \hat{j} + (5y -2x^2y) \hat{k}$$

The line integral yields $\int_{c} F \cdot dr = \frac{230}{3}$, where $c$ is the curve it goes along. It's just stated that $c$ lies on the plane $x + 5y + z = 4$, which is oriented clockwise as seen from above.

I want to find out the curve, which has to be the projection of the plane $x + 5y + z = 4$ on the $xy$ plane.

**The stated solution is** $y^2 - x^2 \le \frac{1}{4}$ **but I don't understand neither why nor the method used.**

Actually, I tried to project the vector perpendicular to the given plane (pointing inwards because of the clockwise direction) onto the xy plane but did not get that.

EDIT

**The problem statement**

> Find the maximum value of $\oint_{c} F \cdot dr$ where $F = 10xy^2 \hat{i} + (4z-2xy^2) \hat{j} + (5y -2x^2y) \hat{k}$ and $c$ is a simple closed curve in the plane $x + 5y + z = 4$ oriented clockwise as seen from high on the z-axis. What curve $c$ gives this maximum?

The maximum value of the closed path integral has been calculated: $\oint_{c} F \cdot dr = \frac{230}{3}$, which occurs when $c$ is the boundary of the plane surface region $S$ (here we recall Stoke's theorem) in $x + 5y + z = 4$ **whose projection onto the xy-plane is** $y^2 - x^2 \le \frac{1}{4}$

The last bold line is what I don't really see. **Maybe the projection is wrong**

All stated options for the projections onto the xy-plane are:

a) $x - y \le \frac{1}{4}$

b) $y - x \le \frac{1}{4}$

c) $x^2 + y^2 \le \frac{1}{4}$

d) $y^2 - x^2 \le \frac{1}{4}$

e) $x + y \le \frac{1}{4}$

f) $x^2 - y^2 \le \frac{1}{4}$

This solved problem states that option d) is correct but could be wrong

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is $C$? Any further context that you can provide would be helpful.

Comment: @CameronBuie $C$ is a simple closed curve in the plane $x + 5y + z = 4$ oriented clockwise (if you are seeing from above; ie the unit vector $\hat{k}$ is pointing at you).

Comment: The projection of the plane $x + 5y + z = 4$ on the $XY$ plane is... the $XY$ plane! Some data missing.

Comment: I am going to attach the problem this issue is coming from

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla You can check the edit out

Comment: As stated, is a problem of calculus of variations... And the answer doesn't makes sense: the supposed projection of $S$ is unbounded!

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla yes, I am also confused with this question. Actually there're more options for the projection; the one stated was the one marked as correct (but it has been solved but another student before; it is not coming from the solution manual). Let me add the other possible options (please see post again)

Comment: Well, the **only** bounded subset is (c). But the problem is *weird*.

Comment: Please feel free to provide an explanation on your argument